# Azure DevOps - Hosted Build Agents not available

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I'm working on a project that utilises Azure DevOps for building our .net core application suite.

Last couple of days we've noticed the builds are being queued for hours, we've paid for additional build time on the Azure Hosted Build Agents but there's just such a wait for the builds.

It seems to be random as sometimes the builds happen right away, we don't have any Azure support plan so I thought i'd ask the question if anyone is experiencing similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to a temporary outage that occurred recently and is now showing as resolved: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/231083118

Comment: Thanks Tom, it's still on going for us, we've had it happen again. I'm wondering if there is a backlog

Comment: I saw this continue the day after and still caused obstacles for us, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to establish first that you're running into a concurrency limit - fortunately, there are now analytics for that in preview in Azure DevOps:

First, enable the feature (bottom of the screen shot):

[image: Enable preview feature]

Then, go to `Project Settings` -> `Agent Pools` -> `Azure Pipelines` -> `Analytics`

[image: Analytics]

It would seem to me that if you're not crossing the "Concurrency" line when this is occurring, you could open a ticket with Microsoft. If you are crossing the line, you would need to determine whether to purchase more parallel jobs, or to self-host.

Comment: Thank you for your response i'll have a chat with the rest of my team to get them to investigate this. Unfortunately, Microsoft won't let us open a ticket because our client hasn't paid for support. I think we made need to go down the self-host route if I'm honest.